# Cannot extract URL of plotly charts (to be embedded into html reports)

Tags: python, embed, plotly

I am trying to print the URL for a plotly chart.

The command:

```
plot_url = py.iplot(fig, filename= 'chart name',auto_open=False)
print plot_url
```

returns:

```
plotly.tools.PlotlyDisplay object>
```

rather than:

```
https://plot.ly/23/~andrea.botti/
```

Any idea why that happens? This is preventing me from embedding the chart into a script that automatically generates a html report when a chart is made.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the answer.
The issue was that I was using `py.iplot` instead of `py.plot`.

Changing the code to:

```
plot_url = py.plot(fig, filename= 'chart name',auto_open=False)
print plot_url
```

outputs the correct url.